# Filter ng-repeat json result against array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-filters

At the moment I have a json result which is displayed in an ng-repeat that I would like to have filtered based on a separate object or array of data:

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.jsonResult = [
 {
   "id": "a123"
 },
 {
  "id": "b456"
 }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<span ng-repeat="r in jsonResult">{{r.id}}</span>
```

What I am attempting to achieve is to create a separate array of info and then use this data to filter the `ng-repeat` results that display in my HTML.

```
$scope.itemsToFilter = ["b456","foo"]
```

Since an item within my `itemsToFilter` array matches an object within my `jsonResult` scope, I would like that not to display within my `ng-repeat` within the HTML. Is this something I should write a custom filter for? Sorry I am very new to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Angular filter which returns the array filtered by items' ids which match your blacklist:

```
angular.module("yourAppName")
.filter("filterArrayByBlacklist", function() {
    blackList = ["b456","foo"];
    return function(array) {
        return array.filter(function(item) {
            return blackList.indexOf(item.id) === -1; // item id not found in blacklist
        });
    };
});
```

You can then filter the ng-repeat by your filter function:

```
<span ng-repeat="r in jsonResult | filterArrayByBlacklist">{{r.id}}</span>
```

See this plnkr for a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/VK3jiVBpL0e1G06WmPZq

Comment: @CaspNZ I'd like to add that you can use "constant" to save your blacklist as a constant array and inject that into a filter. Compared to the accepted answer, this is more extensible since the filter function will only work inside the $scope and child $scopes where the function was declared.

Comment: Yup, using a module constant would be the way to go eh.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by using a custom filter. A quick filter can be written like this:

```
$scope.filterByStrings = function (item) {
    return ($scope.itemsToFilter.indexOf(item.id) === -1);
};
```

And called like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:filterByStrings ">
    <p>{{item.id}}</p>
</div>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rapsac/a5mk2d51/) is the fiddle.

Comment: Yes! - Thank you *very* much CaspNZ - silly error on my part, just couldn't see it! - working fine now.